# Cohomology Group of $CP^2 \wedge CP^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

Calculate the cohomology group of  $CP^2 \wedge CP^2$

To do this, at first I am trying to calculate the homology group and then use Universal Coefficient Theorem.

To do this, at first I have calculated homology groups of $CP^2 \times CP^2$ and $CP^2 \vee CP^2$ then consider the long exact sequence of the pair $(CP^2 \times CP^2 , CP^2 \vee CP^2).$

But I can't calculate the homology group of $CP^2 \wedge CP^2$ for dimension $< 6.$

Comment: The notations are a bit confused... $X \wedge Y$ is the smash product and is equal to $(X \times Y) / (X \vee Y)$, the quotient of the cartesian product by the wedge sum. So you computed the homology of $CP^2 \times CP^2$ and $CP^2 \vee CP^2$, right? And then you consider the pair $(CP^2 \times CP^2, CP^2 \vee CP^2)$?

Comment: @najib idrissi.
yes..I will be thankful to you if you please edit this

Comment: Okay. For future reference, $\vee$ is `\vee`and $\wedge$ is `wedge`. You can right click on a formula and select "Show math as > TeX commands" to see how something was produced. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @najib idrissi.
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$
Let $P = \mathbb{CP}^2 \times \mathbb{CP}^2$ be the cartesian product and $S = \mathbb{CP}^2 \vee \mathbb{CP}^2$ be the wedge sum. Then the smash product is $\mathbb{CP}^2 \wedge \mathbb{CP}^2 =  P / S$. Since $S \subset P$ is a sub-CW-complex, $\tilde{H}^n(P/S) \cong H^n(P,S)$.

It is well known that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^2) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3)$. Thus, respectively by Mayer–Vietoris and Künneth:
$$H^*(S) = \Z[x,y]/(x^3, y^3, xy) \\
H^*(P) = \Z[x,y]/(x^3, y^3)$$
where $x$ corresponds to the first factor and $y$ to the second.

The long exact sequence of the pair $(P,S)$ in cohomology gives:
$$0 \to H^0(P,S) \to H^0(P) \to H^0(S) \to H^1(P,S) \to \dots\\ \to H^n(P,S) \to H^n(P) \to H^n(S) \to H^{n+1}(P,S) \to \dots$$

Since $\dim S = 4$, $H^n(S) = 0$ for $n > 4$, thus for $n > 5$ you find $H^n(P,S) \cong H^n(P)$. And in low dimensions you have:
$$0 \to H^0(P,S) \to \Z \xrightarrow{=} \Z \to H^1(P,S) \to 0 \to 0 \to H^2(P,S) \to \Z x \oplus \Z y \xrightarrow{=} \Z x \oplus \Z y \to H^3(P,S) \to 0 \to 0 \to H^4(P,S) \to \Z xy \oplus \Z x^2 \oplus \Z y^2 \to \Z x^2 \oplus \Z y^2 \to H^5(P,S) \to 0 \to 0 \to H^6(P,S) \to \Z x^2y \oplus \Z xy^2 \to 0 \to H^7(P,S) \to 0 \to 0 \to H^8(P,S) \to \Z x^2y^2 \to 0 \to 0 \to \dots$$
So finally:
$$H^n(\mathbb{CP}^2 \wedge \mathbb{CP}^2) = \begin{cases}
\Z & n = 0 \\
0 & n = 1,2,3 \\
\Z & n = 4 \\
0 & n = 5 \\
\Z \oplus \Z & n = 6 \\
0 & n = 7 \\
\Z & n = 8
\end{cases}$$

Comment: thanks..
why xy=0 in the cohomology ring structure of S ?
 I think x^3=0,y^3=0 in cohomology ring structure of P.right?

Comment: You're right, it was $x^3$ and $y^3$. In $H^*(S)$, $xy = 0$ because they come from two different factors of $\mathbb{CP}^2 \vee \mathbb{CP}^2$. In general, if $\alpha \in H^*(X)$, $\beta \in H^*(Y)$ are of degrees $> 0$, then $\alpha \beta = 0$ in $H^*(X \vee Y)$. See example 3.13 in Hatcher's book for example.